# Option MultiViews inside htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

In .htaccess file inside my `www/public` folder, I see `Options -MultiViews`, could anyone explain to me what this line of code does?

Answer (score 1):

Option `MultiViews` is used by [Apache's content negotiation module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#negotiation) that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.